# Read multipart form data without saving files to disk?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a form which looks, simplified, like this:

```
<form id="image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="imageEntryName" />                                    
  <input type="file" name="imageEntry" />
  <input type="text" name="imageEntryAltText" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND INN" class="btn-ok" />
</form>
```

This is posted to this action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/Exhibition/SubmitImageEntry")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SubmitImageEntry()
{
  if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
  {
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }

  var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("C:/test");
  var data = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

  return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

And this works. I get the posted data. But is this possible without the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` saving files to `C:/test`? I possible, I can just keep the data in memory until the action is completed.

EDIT: With `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` I get the `.FormData["key"]` option, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartmemorystreamprovider(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: That might work, but it gives me all the data in a list, which means I don't know what is what. I can just guess that they will always come in the same order, but if some front end developer rearranged something in the form, he'd break the whole thing.

Comment: I'm not sure this provider does anything different from `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` as seen from the consumer side. Try adding code to your question where you show how you consume the posted data.

Comment: This is all I got, I have just debugged it in the `Watch` window. But, with `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` I get the `.FormData["key"]` option, which is what I want.